# Send start of page's HTML to the server whilst waiting for database

Tags: node.js, koa

If I take out my database access code my webpages are dealt with in a few ms. When the database access code is added then the requests go up to 400ms+.

Is it possible to send the top of the page to the browser whilst waiting on the database to return?

Just to prove this is possible...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please open the developer tools ... and check if your browser completed your tags or not?

Comment: Yes it did complete the tags.

Comment: What about this guy? He doesn't seem to be using Ajax requests in order to 'see the updated screen after each and every second'. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/improving-Asp-Net-performance-using-response-bufferoutput/

Comment: Ok. So your request finished ... since the browser rendered what he got in reply. So you cannot continue to send more data in the finished request. About the link: that is the something similar to `socket.io` he creates a connection that is continuously open. The answer to your question is still NO! And it won't change ... . Please Google or Bing how the web works and how html pages work.

Comment: So why can't I create a connection that is 'continuously open' like that guy? Wouldn't that make the answer to my question be 'yes'?

Comment: Nope.. you would still keep updating your document when new data comes in.

Comment: That's what I want to do.

Comment: But note that that still does not send the "top of the page to the browser". You send the whole page then you update it.

Comment: But a few comments up you said, 'you cannot continue to send more data in the finished request'. And now you're saying, "You send the whole page then you update it". I agree with the first. Not the second.

Comment: Great discussion... http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-lost-art-of-progressive-html-rendering/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marko](https://github.com/raptorjs/marko) does exactly what you are looking for:

It offers 3 key features that enable progressive rendering:

1. Streamed Template Rendering - So your html is sent early and the buffers are cleared often
2. Async Rendering of html fragments - Marko will manage the waiting, buffering and eventual rendering
3. Out of order rendering - Marko will optionally send template data as soon as it is available from api calls or db queries, then it will re-order the html on the client side

I just did a screencast on Marko that you might find helpful:

http://knowthen.com/episode-8-serving-content-in-koajs-with-marko/

Comment: Aha... pity I've currently using Jade.

Comment: It would be nice if you could do this with Jade, but I don't believe there is a way... Kind of a big shortcoming in Jade and almost every other nodejs template engine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to write an HTML fragment to the response stream and flush it before continuing with the request as per normal with Jade?

Comment: Possibly, but likely challenging to do in an elegant way.  I am half tempted to do what author of Marko mentioned in this thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/2sz92j/marko_is_better_than_jade_60_second_proof/cnukl6h

Comment: Exactly... ought to be a separation of concerns here.

Comment: Similar issue with ASP.net MVC http://nikcodes.com/2014/03/04/flushing-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

You should return your views immediately and populate your data with some asynchronous `api` calls (using `ajax` calls) that trigger db queries. When you get your results from the database you can send them. Alternatively you can break up your queries and return chunks of your data if that is what makes more sense.

Comment: I'm not talking about multiple responses. I'm talking about one response that gets delayed in the middle. I think you can send <html> and then wait for </html>. How else would web pages progressively load? Like on slow connections, I'm sure I can recall the scroll bar gradually getting smaller as more content was sent form the server.

Comment: @IanWarburton the thing you need to do is send a complete, but empty, html doc (e.g. <html><!--other skeleton of page here--></html> and then use async calls to update it as results come in or fail.

Comment: Please take a look at these pages (e.g. Facebook). Check how many ajax request are fired. It is fired to load additional data. You can also read about it [here](http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Progressive_loading).

Comment: Socket.io may be useful in this, as may a framework like Angular, Ember, Knockout, etc.

Comment: As I said I don't want to do that because then it makes it difficult to have search engines find the data.

Comment: I know what an AJAX request is. Facebook aren't concerned with having their content indexed by search engines.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I'm not convinced. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69745/discussion-on-answer-by-pio-send-start-of-pages-html-to-the-server-whilst-waiti).